# Accidentally connected USB data pin to 120V AC. Is it worth sending for repair?

Tags: usb, laptop

I accidentally connected a USB data pin to 120V AC. I'm wondering if it's worth bothering to send the laptop in to repair, or if there's no chance it's repairable.

(I was trying to look at a data signal with a cheap USB oscilloscope plugged into the laptop but mixed it up with power)

Comment: "it" is what exactly?

Comment: Does the scope still work? Did you see a flash, or smoke? Or hear a bang?

Comment: "*... mixed it up with power*" -- You really need to be more careful and aware of what you're doing. You're lucky that only some equipment was damaged and you didn't shock yourself. What were you doing near 120VAC while probing USB signals?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I heard a popping sound. The scope no longer works when plugged into another device and the laptop no longer has any indicators turn on when plugged in.

Comment: The laptop was almost certainly also killed.

Comment: Did you connect the scope tip or scope ground to mains live? The scope tip or ground do not directly connect to USB data pin so what you say is maybe not what happened, if you simply touched mains live with some part of probe. Which USB scope it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inexpensive USB oscilloscopes are not simply repairable.  I have experimented with these.

You hooked up 120 VAC to the input. This will kill the input circuit and likely cause other significant damage. The majority of the oscilloscope circuit will likely be on one Integrated Circuit which will be soldered onto the main circuit board.

> I'm wondering if it's worth bothering to send it in to repair

Not likely. You can ask them but they will almost certainly suggest replacing it.

It is also possible the 120 VAC went back through the USB connection to the laptop. You will need to determine if the laptop is worth repair.

Comment: I realize that my post was unclear. The scope is definitely dead. I was asking about the laptop the scope was connected to.

Comment: Is the laptop working?  If not, the 120VAC has gone through the scope to the laptop. You need to determine if the laptop  is worth repairing. I amended my answer to include both situations.